# Multinomial Naive Bayes + neg_log_loss + Machine Learning + Python : How to use neg_log_loss with cross_val_score()

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, cross-validation, naivebayes

I am finding the optimal value of hyperparameter alpha for my Multinpmial Naive Bayes model which uses cross validation and neg_log_loss as metric. I wrote thie code:

```
alphas = list(range(1, 500))

#perform k fold cross validation for different metrics
def cross_val(metric):

    MSE = []
    cv_scores = []
    training_scores = []

    for alpha in alphas:
        naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=alpha)
        scores = cross_val_score(naive_bayes, x_train_counts, y_train, cv=20, scoring='neg_log_loss')                           

        #score() returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels
        scores_training = naive_bayes.fit(x_train_counts, y_train).score(x_train_counts, y_train)

        cv_scores.append(scores.mean())
        training_scores.append(scores_training)


    #changing to misclassification error
    MSE = [1 - x for x in cv_scores]  

    #determining best alpha
    optimal_alpha = alphas[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
    print('\nThe optimal value of alpha for %s is %f' % (metric, optimal_alpha))
    return optimal_alpha


optimal_alpha = cross_val('neg_log_loss')
```

The above code was initially working. Now it's throwing following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-facbaa3537ca> in <module>()
----> 1 optimal_alpha = cross_val('neg_log_loss')
      2 prediction(optimal_alpha, 'neg_log_loss')

<ipython-input-41-ff0a9191d45c> in cross_val(metric)
     13     for alpha in alphas:
     14         naive_bayes = MultinomialNB(alpha=alpha)
---> 15         scores = cross_val_score(naive_bayes, x_train_counts, y_train, cv=20, scoring='neg_log_loss')
     16 
     17         #score() returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1579                                               train, test, verbose, None,
   1580                                               fit_params)
-> 1581                       for train, test in cv)
   1582     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
   1583 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, error_score)
   1692 
   1693     else:
-> 1694         test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1695         if return_train_score:
   1696             train_score = _score(estimator, X_train, y_train, scorer)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1749         score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
   1750     else:
-> 1751         score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
   1752     if hasattr(score, 'item'):
   1753         try:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py in __call__(self, clf, X, y, sample_weight)
    142                                                  **self._kwargs)
    143         else:
--> 144             return self._sign * self._score_func(y, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
    145 
    146     def _factory_args(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in log_loss(y_true, y_pred, eps, normalize, sample_weight, labels)
   1684                              "y_true: {2}".format(transformed_labels.shape[1],
   1685                                                   y_pred.shape[1],
-> 1686                                                   lb.classes_))
   1687         else:
   1688             raise ValueError('The number of classes in labels is different '

ValueError: y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 26, 27. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true: [ 2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 14 15 16 17 19 21 22 23 24 27 29 30 31 32
 33 35]
```

This code worked few times initially. Suddenly, it stopped working. How can I make it work?

Answer (score -1):

Check the shape of x_train_counts & y_train. There is a mismatch between the # of records between them.

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.